# How to deal with a position in list that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, list

I'm building this program in C# in which you can enter membership details, confirm them, and view previously stored memberships. I am still very much a beginner and this is just some school homework.

My teacher suggested to write and read membership details to a file but I had no idea how to do this efficiently so just added them all to a list. I wrote this part to retrieve the username, password and membership type.

However, how do I stop an 'unhandled' error if the user enters a value in which doesn't have any stored data?

Here is the code: the list is called membersList.

```
Console.WriteLine("Which stored membership would you like to view? (e.g 1, 2..)");
int membChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Membership Entry " + membChoice);
Console.WriteLine("Username: " + membersList[membChoice*3-3]);
Console.WriteLine("Password: " + membersList[membChoice*3-2]);
Console.WriteLine("Membership Type: " + membersList[membChoice*3-1].ToUpper());
```

This results in an unhandled exception error if you enter a larger value than members already stored.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you change your call to `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` to use `int.TryParse`; that way you can check that you user entered a valid number, and not something like `two`. Always assume your users can screw things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to check if the list has an element at the position you want:

```
if(list.ElementAtOrDefault(membChoice*3-3) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Username: " + membersList[membChoice*3-3]);
}
```

---

That or you can do a `try` `catch` to catch the error and display something like invalid choice.

Comment: probably you have a copy-paste typo at your first `(membChoice*3-3])`. Other alternative could be checking list `Count` property

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your list is efficient. I understand you save three information for the same object in three different indices.

I think a better way for comprehension when we begin to code, is to create a class for handle all of this information, like a Member class:

```
class Member
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And use this class for **ONLY ONE** index of your list:

```
Member member = new Member() 
               {
                 ID = 1,
                 Name = "Monty Python",
                 Password = "My favorite color is blue",
                 Type = "Knight"
               };


List<Member> membersList = new List<Member>();
membersList.Add(member);
```

After you can retrieve data by searching with ID:

```
Member memberFind = membersList.Find(x => x.ID == membChoice);
```

And then display data:

```
Console.WriteLine("UserName : " + memberFind.Name);
```